# Facing Issue: IntelliTest Exploration Results - stopped

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, intellitest

So i'm working with IntelliTest to generate test cases and i'm on vs 2015 enterprise edition. The project that is under consideration is a Web API (asp.net) and it was developed in vs 2015 community edition.

This is how i'm going about it

- Right Clicking on a Method and selecting RUN INTELLITEST
- The intellitest window pop ups, says "listening to monitored x86 process (cold start)"
- Then it stops randomly!

Consider the image:

[image]

What could be wrong with it? Thanks.